# Prim's Algorithm Implementation in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, graph, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm

I'm trying to implement Prim's Algorithm in Java using for my graph HashMap + LinkedList and a class Edge which contains the connected vertex and the weight:

```
adjacencyList = new HashMap<T, LinkedList<Edge<T>>>();
```

My idea was, starting from a given vertex:
1)save all vertices into a LinkedList so I can remove them every time they've been visisted
2)saving the path into another LinkedList so I can have my final MST
3)using a PriorityQueue to find MIN weight

In the end I'll need MST, number of edges and total weight.
I'm very confused about how to return MST and I have few errors on my code which I have no idea on how to fix them!

First of all I get this error:

```
    Prim.java:21: error: no suitable method found for addAll(LinkedList<Edge<T>>)
        unvisited.addAll(graph.getVertices());
                 ^
    method Collection.addAll(Collection<? extends T>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; LinkedList<Edge<T>> cannot be converted to Collection<? extends T>)
    method List.addAll(Collection<? extends T>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; LinkedList<Edge<T>> cannot be converted to Collection<? extends T>)
    method AbstractCollection.addAll(Collection<? extends T>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; LinkedList<Edge<T>> cannot be converted to Collection<? extends T>)
    method LinkedList.addAll(Collection<? extends T>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; LinkedList<Edge<T>> cannot be converted to Collection<? extends T>)
  where T is a type-variable: T extends Comparable<T> declared in class Prim
```

It seems the problem is in my getVertices() method (which return all the vertices of the graph) as it returns a `Set<T>`; I tried to put everything inside a LinkedList using addAll and get as return this LinkedList but it gives me the same error. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Graph<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    .
    .
    public Set<T> getVertices() {
            if (adjacencyList.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Error message.\n");
                return null;
            } else
                return adjacencyList.keySet();
        }
    }
```

The second error is:

```
   Prim.java:28: error: incompatible types: T cannot be converted to Edge<T>
            for (Edge<T> edge : graph.getAdjacentVertices(source)) {
                                                          ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Comparable<T> declared in class Prim
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
```

I can fix it by casting `Edge<T>` to `source` but I think it doesn't make any sense at all because the idea was that I give a vertex which can contain any type, not only Edges.

Prim's:

```
public class Prim<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    public <SHOULD I RETURN graph ?> minimumSpanningTree(Graph<Edge<T>> graph, T vertex) {
        //ArgumentException

        double weight = 0;
        T source = vertex;

        LinkedList<T> vertexSet = new LinkedList<>();
        LinkedList<Edge<T>> path = new LinkedList<>();

        vertexSet.addAll(graph.getVertices()); //unvisited ERROR HERE
        vertexSet.remove(source);

        double numberOfVertices = graph.getVertices().size();
        PriorityQueue<Edge<T>> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<>();

        while (!vertexSet.isEmpty()) {
            for (Edge<T> edge : graph.getAdjacentVertices(source)) {//ERROR
               if (vertexSet.contains(edge.getDestination())) 
                    priorityQueue.insert(edge);
            }
            Edge<T> minWeight = priorityQueue.extractMin();
            weight += minWeight.getWeight();
            path.add(HERE I SHOULD PUT MST PATH BUT I DON'T KNOW HOW!!);

            source = minWeight.getDestination();
            vertexSet.remove(source);
        }
        return <graph??>;
    }
}
```

As I said before, I don't know if I should return a graph as MST (maybe the one I give as input deleting the most expensive edges) or the LinkedList called path which saves the path with lowest weight.
I also don't know how to find the number of edges in the MST; should I for every vertex (keySet of my HashMap) find the size of the LinkedList (which is its value) and sum them all?

**EDIT: getAdjacentVertices method**

```
public LinkedList<T> getAdjacentVertices(T vertex) {
    if (adjacencyList.isEmpty() || adjacencyList.containsKey(vertex) == false) {
        System.out.println("Error msg.\n");
        return null;
    } else {
        LinkedList<T> allAdjacents = new LinkedList<>();
        for (Edge<T> edge : adjacencyList.get(vertex)) {
            allAdjacents.add(edge.getDestination());
        }
        return allAdjacents;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I guess the error is not in `getVertices()` but in the fact that your `Graph` was defined as generic on `Edge<T>` and not `T`. `Graph<T>` is instantiated as `Graph<Edge<T1>>`, so `Set<T>` as return value is istantiated  as `Set<Edge<T1>>`.

I suggest you define `Graph` as `Graph<Edge<T>>`, and refactor the graph's logics from there, or define a `IEdge<T>` as superinterface of `Edge<T>` and redefine Graph as `Graph<? extends IEdge<T>>`.

For instance (going blindfolded):

```
public class Graph<T> {
    Map<T, Edge<T>> adjacencyList;
    public Set<T> getVertices() {
        if (adjacencyList.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Error message.\n");
            return null;
        } else {
            return adjacencyList.keySet();
        }
    }
}

Graph<Point> p;
List<Point> points = new LinkedList<>();
points.addAll(p.getVertices());
```

2) A variant of 1. In this case, you're returning a `List<T>` but since you're cycling with:

```
for (Edge<T> edge : graph.getAdjacentVertices(source))
```

the return value of `getAdjacentVertices` should be an `Enumerable<Edge<T>>`, while you're providing a `Enumerable<T>`. You probably want to return something like this in your `getAdjacentVertices` implementation:

```
LinkedList<Edge<T>> allAdjacents = new LinkedList<>();
for (Edge<T> edge : adjacencyList.get(vertex)) {
    allAdjacents.add(edge);
}
return allAdjacents;
```

Comment: Ok, worked for (1) but didn't understand which Graph should I define as Graph<Edge<T>> for point (2).
Do you mean the class or the minimumSpanningTree(Graph<T> graph, T vertex)?

Comment: Edited my answer to provide an example. Right now I have no way to test, but you should be able to grasp the juice.

Comment: um ok, I think I got it but this will mess half of my graph class!! I think I'll need to find another solution!

Comment: No problem. Also I wouldn't return null when I can return an empty list ;)

Comment: I've just seen that  you edited it again! This way is what I'm doing and getting the error!

Comment: Yeah, found a fiddle and checked if it compiled. However, you're not doing exactly like this. In your code, you define `minimumSpanningTree(Graph<Edge<T>> graph)` instead of `minimumSpanningTree(Graph<T> graph)`.

Comment: I edited it as minimumSpanningTree(Graph<T> graph) after your answer! I still get only the second error!

Comment: For the second error you would need to post also the signature of `getAdjacentVertices()` and the type of `source` before any specific help can be given.

Comment: Uops sorry, I thought i posted it in the main post but I forget about it! Added now.
I created source as T because a vertex can contain any kind of items. In my case, I'll need a String but it must be able to contain anything!

Comment: Actually I already tried this way but I got the same error as (1): 

    Graph.java:124: error: no suitable method found for add(T)
                    allAdjacents.add(edge.getDestination());
                                ^
        method Collection.add(Edge<T>) is not applicable
          (argument mismatch; T cannot be converted to Edge<T>)
        method List.add(Edge<T>) is not applicable

Comment: Be careful, I guess you've edited the type of `List` but left the `add(edge.getDestination())` unchanged. You can't add a `Edge<T>` to a `List<T>`. Moreover, what's the point of getting the edge destination when in the caller you cycle the result _edges_ and check if your vertexes already contain their _destination_? You want to return `Edge`s, not `T`s.

Comment: This is endless!! By modifying my getDestination method I have to change all my T type in Graph class!
I wanted to get destination to be sure to visit all the connected edges of a single vertex, so, if the edge I'm visiting has not been vistied yet - I'll add it into my priority queue. This was the idea!